# How to compare jenkins BUILD_USER of replay and the original job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way Jenkins knows how to compare between user (user b) who did replay job to the user who ran the original job (user a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Audit Trail plugin** to see the user who did the replay and original job or use the Jenkins REST API to get build information and compare **BUILD_USER** variable of the replay and original build, the API looks like this: `<Jenkins_URL>/job/<Job_Name>/<Build_Number>/api/json`